# Run unit tests against local changed python modules with modules also installed

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, unit-testing

I have a Python lib installed on my system. 
I forked that lib, modified some code and wrote new tests.

Now if I run the unit tests with eclipse, they test against the installed lib and do not consider my local changes.

My workaround was to uninstall the lib (`pip uninstall`) and install my local files (`python setup.py install`). This is annoying as I have to re-install after every change.

Is there a way to run the tests explicit against my local changes with eclipse or via command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular python can't do it and takes the installed modules

`> python src\mod\test.py`

Using [`nosetests`](http://nose.readthedocs.io/) solves this issue. If started inside the fork dir, it takes the local files over the installed lib.

`> nosetests src\mod\test.py`

For running all testcases
`> nosetests`